# PDFBox set Overlay over specific page

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I've written a webapp, which merges a `.pdf` with a `.png` file. Everything works fine, except when the input PDF has multiple pages, because PDFBox has no function for selecting which specific page I want the Overlay on. It only has First,Last, Odd, Even or All pages. I'm using PDFBox first to save the .png on a new PDF. My method of merging uses the .pngPDF as an Overlay and puts it over the input PDF.

My code for merging is as follows:

```
        File file2 = new File(getImagePdfLocation());
        PDDocument overlayDoc = PDDocument.load(file2);
        Overlay overlayObj = new Overlay();

        PDDocument originalDoc = PDDocument.load(new File("Path"));
        overlayObj.setOverlayPosition(Overlay.Position.FOREGROUND);
        overlayObj.setInputPDF(originalDoc);
        overlayObj.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(overlayDoc);      //alternatives?
        Map<Integer, String> ovmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();            
        overlayObj.overlay(ovmap);
        originalDoc.save("Path");

        overlayDoc.close();
        originalDoc.close();
```

Is there any function I'm overlooking, or can you suggest a workaround?

I have a Javascript which retrieves the current page number and passes it to my bean, all I need is a way to set it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it was quite easy. You just have to make an entry to the map with the desired page number and the filepath to the overlay.

Like so:

```
    ovmap.put(2, "Path");
```